# How to search objects in django using an instance of choicefield?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
    user_types = (
        ('Business User','Business User'),
        ('Professional','Professional'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=32,choices=user_types,default='Business User',blank=False)
    user= models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
```

As you can see the are two types of user in my `Profile` model `Business User` and `Professional`. So I want to make a query in django which will search only for the `Professional` users.

I have tried this in my views:

```
    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if query:
        if Profile.objects.filter(user_type__icontains='Professional'):
            result = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(e_mail__icontains=query) | Q(full_name__icontains=query))
    else:
       result = Profile.objects.filter(user_type__icontains='Professional').order_by('id')
```

In my template:

```
       <form method='GET' class="form-horizontal" id="search-form" action="{% url 'userprofile:search' %}">

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
          <input  class="form-control" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="Search">

        </div>

      <div >

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Go</button>
        </span>

      </div>


    </form>
```

But when I search for a `Professional` user it gives me list of all the user associated with that name.

Can anyone provide me with suitable solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved It**

Done the following in my view and it worked:

```
user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_type__icontains='Professional')

query = request.GET.get('q')

if query:
    result = user_profile.filter(Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(e_mail__icontains=query) | Q(full_name__icontains=query))
else:
    result = Profile.objects.filter(user_type__icontains='Professional').order_by('id')
```